# location.href works like browser back button click in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with a big application, in that most of the pages are already build and the current architecture use `location.href` for changing the url. We are using `angularJS` and I know it is not the right way to do routing in `angularJS` but changing everywhere will be a headache. 
The issue is I have a requirement that to show a dynamic breadcrumb in each page, and it should show the correct breadcrumb path when a user click on browser back button. I have created a history array for the same and when ever a browser back button click event happens I will remove one item from array and push last item  to breadcrumb. Everything works fine with links as url, but logic fails when the redirection is happens inside a function like below

```
location.href="#/dashboard";
```

This below code is treated as a browser back button click by code. Below is my back button detecting code .

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
        $rootScope.actualLocation = $location.path();
    });        
   $rootScope.$watch(function () {return $location.path()}, function (newLocation, oldLocation) {

        if($rootScope.actualLocation === newLocation) {
            //logic
        }
        else{
            //logic
        }
    });
```

I can use a `rootScope` variable for condition check before each redirection code , but it is not a proper solution because the redirection code is there in more than 500 places in the application.

So is there anyway to detect whether the call is coming from a browser back button or from some `location.href` ??

Comment: What I know , you can't detect or get  browser back button click event using js.

Comment: you can try to play with window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {}); -- seems like triggers only on Back/Forward